# How to create any code from google spreadsheet like {.label} by Craft CMS

Tags: error-message, error

ex) original HTML source code

```
<link rel="exhibit/data" type="application/jsonp" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/~~~~/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script" ex:converter="googleSpreadsheets" />
```

~~~~~

```
<td valign="top" padding="0.5em">
    <span style="text-alight:left;" ex:content=".label"></span><br />
    <b>Aired: </b><span ex:content=".start"></span><br />
    <b>Genre: </b><span ex:content=".genre"></span><br />
</td>
```

You can see .label, .start, and .genrem but on Craft CMS they are errors.

How do I create code with no errors?

**Error message is,**

Internal Server Error

Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ".".

*The error message displays like this on my PC's XAMPP
craft/templates/index,html
[image]

Thanks in advance!

**ref image on google spreadsheet,**
[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm following... where are you getting the error?  Can you enabled devMode and share the full stack trace leading up to the error? Are you trying to get data into a format that Google Spreadsheet can recognize?

Comment: I edit and add the error message image. I already have a simile's timeline website like http://relationworld.com/adrama/timeline/drama/top_menu/adrama_title_all-timeline.html    I'd like to use simile's timeline on Craft CMS not using Google Spreadsheet. But I don't find the way of changing from spreadsheet to craft's fields. ex) .label to {{ entry.label }}, but doesn't work  or using spreadsheet then doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use valid html/twig in your templates. Your “HTML Source Code” is not valid html. Removing the `.` from the beginning of your attributes i.e.: `<span ex:content="genre">` should resolve the error, but it still wont be good html.

Best option, IMHO, is to start with a good solid foundation of valid html and work up from there.